# How can I randomize the public Transform tilePrefab in my code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

So I want to make a map generator and have a prefab for a tile. But I want to make more tiles which it randomly chooses from.

How can I make it that tilePrefab is chosen randomly every time from an array of prefabs?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform tilePrefab; //This is the part which I want to be random
    public Vector2 mapSize;

    private void Start()
    {
        GenerateMap();
    }
    public void GenerateMap()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mapSize.x; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapSize.y; y++)
            {
                Vector3 tilePosition = new Vector3(-mapSize.x / 2 + 0.5f + x, 0,-mapSize.y / 2 + 0.5f + y);
                Transform newTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, tilePosition, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * 360)) as Transform;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want that tilePrefab is chosen randomly every time a tile gets generated.

Comment: One approach could be to make an array of the prefabs and then just by using the random index for example...Or assign the random coordinates each time you `Instantiate`

Answer (score 0):

Have an array that holds all the tile prefabs. Randomly choose an index for your new tile.

```
            Transform newTile = Instantiate(tilePrefabs[Random.Range(0, tilePrefabs.Length - 1), tilePosition, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.right * 360)) as Transform;
```